# Are public accessors needed for an inner class, if only accessed from the outer class?

Tags: java

Since i can access `private` variables of an inner class directly and ... the only way to access `inner` class is via the `outer` class .. **is there any value in having public accessor/ mutator methods for an inner class?**

```
public class Outer {
    Inner   i;

    Outer() {
        i.v = 5;
    }

    private class Inner {
        private int v;
    }  
}
```

For the purposes of this question, assume that no lazy instantiation or other data manipulation is needed upon access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, making the fields non-private would avoid synthetic methods being created to access those private members. In your example, the compiled `Outer$Inner` class contains a synthetic method like this:

```
static int access$002(Outer$Inner, int);
   Code:
      0: aload_0
      1: iload_1
      2: dup_x1
      3: putfield      #1                  // Field v:I
      6: ireturn
```

Maybe that will be inlined down to nothing, maybe it won't... but unless there's any *reason* to force its existence, why not just give `v` the default access?

As for using accessor methods rather than using the fields directly... that's more of a matter of taste. You can't *prevent* the outer class having direct access to the fields, so it's a *little* like asking whether you should create accessors for private fields within a class.

As mentioned in another answer, using accessors makes it more refactoring-friendly. Is the nested class *just* an implementation detail which will *never* need to move? If so, maybe that's fine. I find that if I've got a class like that which is *just* encapsulating fields with no other behaviour, I make the fields public (within a private class, don't forget) to advertise "Hey, I'm not checking anything here..."

Comment: Really? I thought the compiler will always create the synthetic method for inner classes.

Comment: @emory: Not if the access is allowed without any synthetics being required. At least, not the version of javac I'm running :)

Answer (score 1):

If at some later point you might expose your Inner object thru a function call or in some other way, then yes it is important. It might also be important for synchronization purposes, depending on what's going on in your Inner class